# Openrowset bulk file access denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I'm having issues executing an openrowset from a UNC path, receiving the error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\\computer2\path\file.xml" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

For reference, the specific t-sql code is:

```
select full_xml from openrowset(bulk '\\computer2\path\file.xml', Single_BLOB) as T(full_xml)
```

I'm using Sql Logins, with a gMSA running the service.  The gMSA has full read/write access to the UNC path (backups going to the same UNC path work just fine).  I can also copy file.xml to a local path, and the openrowset works as expected.

**EDIT:**
I am not using a Sql Login for the connection to the db.  I'm using a Windows domain account, which also has full access to the UNC path.  Following @lptr's suggestion (in comments/chat), when I connect using a Sql Login, everything works as expected.  I'm still getting the same error when connecting using my domain account.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the SQL Server Service Account  has access to that location? The fact that you are getting that error is a strong pointer that it does not.

Comment: @Larnu, I'm sure as I can be.  `BACKUP DATABASE dbname TO DISK = '\\computer2\path\dbname.bak'` is continuing to work just fine.

Comment: Then that suggests that the file doesn't exist. I would check the UNC path is spelt correctly.

Comment: I'm literally copying/pasting the path and filename.  The file exists, and is available at that UNC path.  `notepad.exe \\computer2\path\file.xml` correctly opens the file

Comment: I hate to say it, but it's very likely to be one, or the other. Either the filepath is incorrect, of the SQL Server service account doesn't have access.  If you run notepad under the credentials of the SQL Server Service Account, you'll probably get a access denied to either read or write the file.

Comment: does this execute ? `restore filelistonly from DISK = '\\computer2\path\dbname.bak'`

Comment: @lptr, yes the `restore filelistonly` executes correctly.

Comment: @Larnu, I just opened the xml file from db server via `.\PsExec.exe -i -u domain\gMSA$ -p ~ notepad.exe` then File->Open to the UNC path.  I also attempted to open a file on a different UNC path that the gMSA does not have access to and received a file access error.

Comment: select full_xml from openrowset(bulk '\\computer2\path\dbname.bak', Single_BLOB) as T(full_xml)  --??

Comment: skipping the variable gives the same error - edited question to simply code sample

Comment: ...openrowset the bak file...

Comment: @lptr, `select full_xml from openrowset(bulk '\\computer2\path\dbname.bak', Single_BLOB) as T(full_xml)` gives the access error... ideas for a cause/fix?

Comment: execute as login='sa'; select full_xml from openrowset(........ if this works, make sure you are executing openrowset with a sql login (the sql service account is used for sql logins). if you use windows auth then the windows user needs access to the file & source location

Comment: @lptr, `execute as login='sa'` didn't change anything - I'm still getting the access error when the file is at a remote location, and everything works correctly when the file is at a local path.

Comment: execute as login does not change the security context for openrowset for a windows authenticated user... my mistake. How do you connect to sql server? Are you using a username and password? try to connect with sa (or any other sql login which has bulk operation permissions) and a password and openrowset() again. If you are connecting to sql server with windows authentication then the windows user you are using needs to have access to the file location (and be delegated properly). since backup has read/write to the share if openrowset() is executed with a sql login then it should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210251/discussion-between-chezy525-and-lptr).